# WPF UserControl fill mainwindow

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, viewusercontrol

I am having trouble getting my UserControl to properly fill/resize with the parent window. I'm writing a WPF application using MVVM. I've searched for other answers, and I haven't been able to figure this out.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="QiXR.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:QiXR.ViewModel"
    xmlns:vw="clr-namespace:QiXR.View"
    Title="MainWindow">
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:XRTestCaseListViewModel}">
        <vw:XRTestCaseListView/>
    </DataTemplate>

</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModels}" />
</Grid>
```

UserControl

```
<UserControl x:Class="QiXR.View.XRTestCaseListView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="DataGridCheckBoxStyle" TargetType="CheckBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type CheckBox}}">
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="160"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="160"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="45"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Here's what the display looks like when I launch it
[UserControl in MainWindow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4M0AQ.png)

Is it possible to do this in the xaml of either the UserControl or MainWindow? Thanks

Comment: Looks like how it should be.  Items in an ItemsControl are sized to their own height.  Why have it in an ItemsControl?  Are you expected to have multiple different views in there?

Comment: When you say you expect the space below the buttons to be collapsed, do you mean the window height should be the size of the items control and buttons? Or that the buttons should be at the bottom of the window and the window stays a fixed size?

Comment: @Will Yeah I intend to have more than one view (3 specifically). I changed the ItemsPanelTemplate per Rachel's suggestion below and achieved the behavior I was looking for. However, I'm not married to using ItemsControl generally, it's just the thing that I found doing google searches. (total noob here btw). I'd be open to suggestions for other ways to display views :)

Comment: @JayT I was looking for the former as opposed to the latter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An [ItemsControl](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/wpf-itemscontrol-example/) defaults to using a `StackPanel` to display data, and `StackPanel` limits its size to the size of its children.

Try switching the `ItemsPanelTemplate` to something like a `DockPanel` instead if you only have one item in your `ViewModels` collection :

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModels}">
    <!-- ItemsPanelTemplate -->
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <DockPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

You'll also have to set the `ItemContainerStyle` property for `DockPanel.Dock="Top"` if you plan on having more than one item, perhaps with a converter so the last item is `DockPanel.Dock="Fill"`. Or switch to use a different panel type that also stretches to fill all available space, and allows it's children to stretch as well.

That said, I'd recommend switching to using a `ContentControl` instead of an `ItemsControl` if you are only displaying one item.

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding MyViewModel}" />
```

Comment: Changing the ItemsPanelTemplate did the trick! Thanks Raghel!

Answer (score -1):

If you're looking to have the window be the size of the content (including the menu and buttons below the ItemsControl) with the option to have the window grow bigger if more content is available, you can set the SizeToContent property:

```
<Window x:Class="Project.Window"
    x:Name="userControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Width="400" MaxHeight="700"
    SizeToContent="Height" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">

</Window>
```

The window will grow in height to fit its contents. In there, you could also set the MaxHeight property so that the window doesn't get too large if the ItemsControl has quite a few items in it.